# Create a simple resistive heating element on PCB with Altium

Tags: pcb-design, resistance, altium, heat, passive-components

I have created a component with a simple pattern using tracks and arcs as shown in the link below.

[How to Build Custom PCB Heater Elements](https://maker.pro/pcb/tutorial/how-to-build-custom-pcb-heater-elements)

However, Altium DRC is throwing errors since I have used 2 different pads on both the ends of the element track/arc, which are used to power the element.

Can anyone shed some light on how to make a proper resistive element heating component?

Thanks

Comment: Google (or search on this site) the terms "Altium net tie".

Comment: Related: [signal ground and power ground](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143978/signal-ground-and-power-ground/143980#143980)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and yes Net-Tie is the correct thing to use for this work.

Here are few references if anyone needs.

[Intentionally Connecting Two Nets](https://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/((Creating+Connectivity))_AD#!CreatingConnectivity-IntentionallyConnectingTwoNets)

[Using Net Ties to Meet PCB Design Requirements](https://resources.altium.com/whitepapers/using-net-ties-to-meet-pcb-design-requirements)

[Net Ties and How to Use Them - SMTnet](https://smtnet.com/library/files/upload/NetTies-and-How-to-Use-Them.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I did something like this. The approach I took was a bit different. I created two components that had a single pad each. On the schematic, I connected these components together with a trace. In the layout, I created a serpentine trace to join the two components together. DRC was happy. Everything was fine. Instead of having a heater component, I had a heater PCB.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for the reply. I like your approach and its easy for the single pattern designs. However, it would be easier and time-saving if we know how to make a component and use it repeatedly in complex designs like series of similar patterns required. I think Net-Tie should work will try and see.